# css image border removing left and right borders and duplicating top and bottom

Tags: html, css

so this is the photo I'm using:https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/border2-2.png
and this is my code:

```css
    div{height:234px;
        width:711px;
        border-width:20px;
        padding: 20px 20px;
        text-align:center;}
 #repeat{-webkit-border-image: url(https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/border2-2.png) 0 29.5% repeat;}
```

```html
       <p><div id="repeat">repeating image border</div></p>
```

I tried editing many things in the slices, but it either gave me a white photo (probably the center of the image) or making the duplicates closer. I even tried the code of the site but didn't work either.